# Taylor expansion in linear stability analysis of diffusion-driven instability

Tags: partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, stability-theory, parabolic-pde

We are shown an (apparently trivial) Taylor expansion for a system of reaction-diffusion equations (re Turing stability), where $D$ is a constant:
$$
\frac{\partial\vec u}{\partial t} = D\nabla^2\vec u\,+\,\bar F (\vec u)
$$
For a small perturbation $\vec w$ about a steady-state $\vec u_s$ (s.t. $\vec F(\vec u_s)=0$), we have:
$$
\vec u = \vec u_s+\vec w
$$
And the taylor series linear expansion is given as:
$$
\frac{\partial\vec w}{\partial t} \approx D\nabla^2\vec w\,+\,\vec F (\vec u_s) + \mathbf{J}\vec w
$$
Where $\mathbf{J}$ is the jacobian of $\vec F$ evaluated at $\vec u_s$, and of course the second term above is zero.

I'm a little confused as to how this final equation is reached - I tried doing out the taylor expansion myself but got $\vec u_s$ in the first term instead of $\vec w$.

Comment: What do you mean 'but got $\vec{u}_{s}$ in the first term instead of $\vec{w}$'. Do you mean you got $D \nabla^{2} \vec{u}_{s}$ instead of $D \nabla^{2} \vec{w}$ in the last equation?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Well you should have _both_ a term $D \nabla^{2} \vec{u}_{s}$ _and_ a term $D \nabla^{2} \vec{w}$. Then note that as $\vec{u}_{s}$ solves the stationary problem $$\nabla^{2} \vec{u}_{s} + \vec{F}(\vec{u}_{s}) = 0$$ with $\vec{F}(\vec{u}_{s}) = 0 \dots$

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue myself. Taking the TS expansion of $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{u_s}+\mathbf{w})$, we achieve the second two terms in the final expression above. Fine. What I didn't understand was why the final expression ommited the term $D\nabla^2\mathbf{u_s}$. In the Turing stability case, we have a *spatially uniform steady state*, therefore this term is zero and we get the result stated.